# Por que checkbox aparece seleccionado?

Tags: html, angular, materialize

Tengo el siguiente codigo...

```
<mz-checkbox-container>
  <input mz-checkbox
     id="select-all-{{i}}-{{index}}" 
     type="checkbox"
     (change)="selectCheck(i)"
     [(ngModel)]="cards[i].valueFlights[index]">
</mz-checkbox-container>
```

Ese checkbox me esta saliendo seleccionado, cuando en ningún momento en el código, he escrito que salga así.

Quisiera que me ayudaran a solucionar esto, para que salga sin seleccionarse.

NOTA: 
- El checkbox lo estoy trayendo de materialize https://sherweb.github.io/ngx-materialize/checkbox
- ngModel trae del componente un array de booleanos

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor de `cards[i].valueFlights[index]`? Si no es false este checkbox se marcará

Comment: cards esta declarado asi

Comment: cards: {valueCard:boolean, valueFlights: boolean[]}[]

Comment: Los estoy inicializando en false

Comment: Eso es lo extraño; sabiendo que los estoy inicializando en false, porque aparecen seleccionados